# Comet library for android

Tags: java, android, comet

Task: Send messages from server to the android client with response-time minimization.

I've been told that COMET is a good way to perform it. I found [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/) link, but as a client side code only javascript is shown. So, it is neccesary to implement it in java, but I wonder is there any ready comet library for android of for pure java?

Or are there some other good ways to perform messaging?

I want to highlight that server-polling is not acceptable, as it requires much traffic and is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [cloud to device messaging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html) (C2DM) services to get push notifications when new data is available at the server? Does this yield enough "response time minimization"?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there any links about how does this work? How much time does it get to obtain message from the c2dm server? Is it less than a second or may be 2-3 seconds?

Comment: I actually don't have used it myself (but I plan to). From experience with the other push services offered by Google (e.g. Mail, Market) it is quite fast (usually < 5 seconds). As far as I understood a connection is kept open to Google's C2DM server, so it should be rather fast. However, Google -- again as far as I know -- did not make any guarantees about response times.